# How to call JS function whenever a field equals certain length?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that currently runs whenever the user clicks/tabs out of the employee_number field. I would like it to run whenever the length of the numbers entered is equal to 6, without having to leave the field, since when I try using the tab, it conflicts with loading the next field which is a drop-down that is part of the function ran.

I tried by running it using .change and putting the constraint within the function, but it did not work and I don't know what else to try.

**enter_exit.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load core_tags staticfiles %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" data-employee-activity-lookup-url="{% url 'operations:employee_activity_search' %}" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="employee-name" style="margin-bottom: 10px">&nbsp;</div>
                <label>Employee #</label>
                {{ form.employee_number }}

            </div>

            <div=>
                <label>Work Area</label>
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div style="display: none" id="my-hidden-div">
                <label>Station</label>
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>

        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button>Enter Area</button>
                <button>Exit Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>

        // Grab the employee name and their current active work log (if any)
        $(document).on('blur', "#{{ form.employee_number.id_for_label }}", function(){
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr('data-employee-activity-lookup-url');
            var employeeId = $(this).val();
           # ... more fields ...

            if (employeeId !== "") {

              # .. Rest of function ...
        })
     </script>

{% endblock main %}
```

I also tried using keydown/keyup, but it would not even produce a call to the function. This is how I modified the JS

```
$("#{{ form.employee_number.id_for_label }}").keydown(()=>{
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr('data-employee-activity-lookup-url');
            var employeeId = $(this).val();
            console.log(1); //Not even this appears

            if (employeeId === 6) {
                ...
            }
        })
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: When you look at your rendered source code, is `$("#{{ form.employee_number.id_for_label }}")` being parsed as a valid `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your id selector (`"#{{ form.employee_number.id_for_label }}"`) is being parsed into a valid reference (`"#id-1234-abc"`, for example), your next issue will be your conditional:

```
if (employeeId === 6) {…
```

That tests whether the input value, `$(this).val()`, is `6` — not how many characters. For that, you would want something like:

```
if ( employeeId.length === 6) {…
```